# Feedback on my Latin note on the story of Admetus and Alcestis

Tags: contemporary-latin, new-latin, mythology

I’ve written a little précis of the story of Admetus and Alcestis, and would appreciate any corrections or comments.  I’m mostly concerned about whether I got the tenses of the subjunctive verbs right, but any suggestions are welcome.  You can find the story in Euripides’ *Alcestis*, and Apollodorus’ Bibliotheca 1.9.15.

> Admētus dē Apolline bonum accēpit ut, cum moribundus esset, dē morte līberārētur sī alius quisquam prō eō vītam suam voluntāriē relinqueret.  Cum nec pater nec māter Admētī, quamquam ambō senectūte iam fatīgātī erant, prō fīliō morī voluisset, Alcestis uxor sē obtulit ut prō marītō vicāriā morte interīret.  Herculēs autem eam mortuam ab īnferīs redēmit.